# Polymorphic sorting conversion in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need help with the below problem.  First I have listed the Numbers.java, and below that is my attempt at Strings.java.  Please help!

1. Write a program Strings.java, similar to Numbers.java, that reads in an array of String objects and sorts them. You may just copy and edit Numbers.java.

   ```
   package hw05;

   /*  
   Demonstrates selectionSort on an array of integers.
   */ 

   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class Numbers {  
   // --------------------------------------------  
   // Reads in an array of integers, sorts them,  
   // then prints them in sorted order.  
   // --------------------------------------------  
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Integer[] intList;
       int size;

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("\nHow many integers do you want to sort? ");
       size = scan.nextInt();
       intList = new Integer[size];

       System.out.println("\nEnter the numbers...");
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           intList[i] = scan.nextInt();
       Sorting.selectionSort(intList);

       System.out.println("\nYour numbers in sorted order...");
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           System.out.print(intList[i] + " ");
       System.out.println();

   }
   }
   ```

My Strings class

```
package hw05;

/*
Demonstrates selectionSort on an array of strings.
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Strings {
    // --------------------------------------------
    // Reads in an array of strings, sorts them,
    // then prints them in sorted order.
    // --------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] stringList;
        String size;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nHow many strings do you want to sort? ");
        size = scan.nextLine();
        stringList = new String[size];

        System.out.println("\nEnter the strings...");
        for (String i = 0; i < size; i++)
            stringList[i] = scan.nextLine();
        Sorting.selectionSort(stringList);

        System.out.println("\nYour strings in sorted order...");
        for (String i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.print(stringList[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I need to convert the numbers.java program to read in and sort an array of String objects.

Comment: >You may just copy and edit Numbers.java. I don't think it would happen unless you explain what is exactly the problem you are facing with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get an error because of this declaration here:

```
String size;
```

As you are using it later as an integer:

```
stringList = new String[size];
```

You should use Integer.parse like this:

```
stringList = new String[Integer.parseInt(size)];
```

But you are using size later again for your loops, so I would suggesting reverting it back to an int like you have in your Numbers.java. Be sure to change your scanner back to:

```
scan.nextInt();
```

Other than this, I can't see any other problems. Maybe if you posted the output and pointed out what wasn't working?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer[] intList;
  int size;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("\nHow many strings do you want to sort? ");
  size = scan.nextInt();
  stringList = new String[Integer.parseInt(size)];
  System.out.println("\nEnter the strings...");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   intList[i] = scan.nextInt();
  Sorting.selectionSort(intList);
  System.out.println("\nYour strings in sorted order...");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   System.out.print(intList[i] + " ");
  System.out.println();
                
 }
}

Comment: that's because now you are attempting to parse an int from a string with the line `stringList = new String[Integer.parseInt(size)];` You need to change this back to `stringList = new String[size];` In the future, please explain the error you are getting so it is easier to locate the issue.